# Migration tool to migrate data from 2010 to 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, content-migration

If I migrate the content from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 via third party migration tool, could we upgrade the site collection successfully passing by the custom solutions errors that might occur if database attach upgrade method is used?

Comment: If you plan to upgrade content db with database attach method, what is the purpose to use migration tool?

Comment: pls read my question again.

Comment: if you migrate your contetnt to SP2013, why do you need to upgrade site collection using attach db method? To migrate content using 3rd party tools, you should already have SP2013 environment. you can migrate selected content leaving trash. so you will have fresh SP2013 with migrated content. Custom solutions should be redone to support 2013 version in both cases. Success of upgrading with attach db method doesn't depend on content (which you want to migrate with tool) itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you migrate content only with the tool, yes you might bypass the warning messages you get when doing a database attach migration. You may still encounter problems depending on what these customizations did.

In our experience with using a third party tool to go from 2010 to SPO, all of the customizations we knew of were not carried over (obviously) and did not pose any major issues.  There were a couple pages here and there using a custom web part. Those were stripped out when the pages were migrated.